# android creating search ui similar to Searchable

Tags: android

i need to implement the android search ,my default values is a Arraylist and search result is cursor object ,so i go for my own search ,but i need the search ui similar to android search ui,how can i create this ,please help me,i have tried a lot ,but i won't get this perfection[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appIcon"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_width="39dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/angiicon" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="243dp"
                android:id="@+id/rr1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appIcon"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/categoryListEditText"
                    android:layout_width="202dp"
                    android:text=" "
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:hint="Search Angie’s List"
                    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:paddingRight="34dp"

                    />
                   <Button android:id="@+id/buttonClearText"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:background="@drawable/clear_button"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/categoryListEditText"/>
                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/ProgressBarcat"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/companySearch"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/companySearch"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_search_dialog"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
                    android:layout_width="43dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0.05dp"
                    android:layout_height="41dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />




            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

*You don't have to create Search UI  as android has already given a method to activate this Search UI on user click
    You can call on  **onSearchRequested()** method on Menu click and **add** following things in the **manifest.xml**

```
   1)<!-- Receives the search request -->
                <intent-filter>
                    <action
                        android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                    <category
                        android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
                <!-- Points to searchable meta-data -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.searchable"
                    android:resource="@xml/searchable" />*
```

2) Create a searchable.xml in a res/xml Folder

After this the search interface will be directly called by the action written in the intent-filter